# Launch Reflector from Visual Studio 2008 References Section in Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper, reflector

How do you configure Visual Studio 2008 to launch the Redgate .Net Reflector from a right click on an assembly in the references section in the solution explorer?  I have it set up at the office to do this, so I know it's possible.

I do have ReSharper installed but I don't think this is ReSharper functionality.

**UPDATE**

This is the functionality I'm looking for...

[alt text http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1266849634078638500.jpg](http://www.imagechicken.com/uploads/1266849634078638500.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have Reflector 6 or 5?

If you have 5, then you need TestDriven.Net.

If you have 6 you don't need TestDriven but you will need to right click on the refence -> View in Object Browser, then right click on the assembly and choose Open in .Net Reflector

v 6 also added the integration in the code editor of VS, so you can right click on an object's name and choose Open in .Net Reflector ... which may actually be used more than looking at the whole assembly (via the object browser).

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure it's TestDriven.net from what I've seen now.  Trying to find out how to configure this (i.e. where to enter the file path reference for Reflector.exe)

Comment: Yep, it is TestDriven.Net.  It asks you for the install location of Reflector when you first click on "Go To Reflector".  It also gives you the option of downling it there and then. :-)

Comment: *downloading it there and then